# Condition for function and loop

Tags: r, function, loops, conditional-statements

I have a data frame simplified as follow:

```
head(dendro)
  X            DateTime   ID diameter dendro ring DOY month mday year Rain_mm_Tot Through_Tot temp
1 1 2012-06-21 13:45:00 r1_1     5482      1    1 173     6   22  113          NA          NA   NA
2 2 2012-06-21 13:45:00 r2_3       NA      3    2 173     6   22  113          NA          NA   NA
3 3 2012-06-21 13:45:00 r1_2     5534      2    1 173     6   22  113          NA          NA   NA
4 4 2012-06-21 13:45:00 r2_4       NA      4    2 173     6   22  113          NA          NA   NA
5 5 2012-06-21 13:45:00 r1_3     5606      3    1 173     6   22  113          NA          NA   NA
6 6 2012-06-21 13:45:00 r2_5       NA      5    2 173     6   22  113          NA          NA   NA
```

The dataframe is first splitted by "ID", so it's a list of IDs
After that I apply a function, that includes a loop, and the result is a new column "Diameter2", with the result I want from the function, that works OK:

```
dendro_sp <- split(dendro, dendro$ID)

library(changepoint)

dendro_sp <- lapply(dendro_sp, function(x){

 x <- subset(x, !is.na(diameter))
 cpfit <- cpt.mean(x$diameter, method="BinSeg")

 x$diameter2 <- x$diameter
 cpts <- cpfit@cpts
 means <- param.est(cpfit)$mean
 meanZero <- means[1]

 for(i in 1:(length(cpts)-1)){
   x$diameter2[(cpts[i]+1):cpts[i+1]] <- x$diameter2[(cpts[i]+1):cpts[i+1]] + (meanZero - means[i+1])
 }

 return(x)
})
dendro2 <- do.call(rbind, dendro_sp)
rownames(dendro2) <- NULL
```

My problem is that I want it to apply it conditionally, for example to r1_1 and r1_3, and grab the "diameter" value for r3 in the new column "diameter2", instead of applying the function for the rest of IDs:

```
ifelse(diameter$ID==c("r1_1","r1_3"), apply_the_function_to_r11_and_r13_to_calculate_diameter2, otherwise_write_diameter_value_in_diameter2_column)
```

Remember that the dataframe "dendro" is splitted by ID, I don't know if that is important to define the condition for several IDs.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the problem correctly. I try to answer.
I assume you want to apply a function to the "diameter" field of the "diameter" data.frame, conditioning on the "ID" field and retunr the result in the corresponding diameter2 field. I don't know how the function works, so forgive me if this will not work.

## Selected fields

diameter$diameter2[diameter$ID=="r1_1"|diameter$ID=="r1_3"]<- yourfun(diameter$diameter[diameter$ID=="r1_1"|diameter$ID=="r1_3"]

## Unselected fields

diameter$diameter2[diameter$ID!="r1_1" & diameter$ID=="r1_3"]<- diameter$diameter[diameter$ID=="r1_1"|diameter$ID=="r1_3"]